# Why I'm getting these random [UFW BLOCK] requests in my syslogs?

Tags: 22.04, log, ufw

I just noticed large numbers of these random requests getting blocked by UFW

```
9:34 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=193.254.3.18 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=56991 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53380 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:34 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=66.175.220.229 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=30851 PROTO=TCP SPT=51982 DPT=7707 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:34 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=66.175.220.229 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=45967 PROTO=TCP SPT=51982 DPT=7382 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:33 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=198.235.24.92 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x60 TTL=250 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=50707 DPT=20000 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:33 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=167.94.138.138 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=43 ID=28554 PROTO=TCP SPT=40419 DPT=1200 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:33 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=27.121.102.61 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=52 TOS=0x02 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=7739 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51796 DPT=3306 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:32 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=94.102.61.35 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=166 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=54321 PROTO=UDP SPT=42600 DPT=49155 LEN=146    kernel
9:32 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=65.49.1.74 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=55861 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47489 DPT=19 LEN=9  kernel
9:32 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=146.88.241.199 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=84 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=242 ID=54321 PROTO=UDP SPT=1701 DPT=1701 LEN=64  kernel
9:31 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=112.37.142.191 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=46 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=10758 DPT=123 LEN=12    kernel
9:31 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=14.225.67.147 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=60161 PROTO=TCP SPT=59527 DPT=51389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:31 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=173.230.140.35 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=25347 PROTO=TCP SPT=51934 DPT=5743 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:30 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=35.203.211.190 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x60 TTL=250 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=50268 DPT=9642 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:30 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=220.126.92.34 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=6162 PROTO=TCP SPT=5460 DPT=37215 WINDOW=12660 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  kernel
9:30 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=162.142.125.254 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=41 ID=65319 PROTO=TCP SPT=6973 DPT=7112 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:29 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=222.110.11.183 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=123 LEN=12  kernel
9:29 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=103.254.71.236 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=36298 PROTO=TCP SPT=56453 DPT=59206 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:29 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=79.124.62.130 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xE0 TTL=246 ID=1337 PROTO=TCP SPT=57174 DPT=50349 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:28 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=162.216.150.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x18 PREC=0xA0 TTL=59 ID=52322 PROTO=TCP SPT=52909 DPT=1023 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  kernel
9:28 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=35.203.211.130 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x18 PREC=0xA0 TTL=59 ID=51060 PROTO=TCP SPT=56494 DPT=14025 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:28 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=125.142.6.219 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=123 LEN=12   kernel
9:27 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=91.191.209.198 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xE0 TTL=247 ID=53471 PROTO=TCP SPT=41936 DPT=3981 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:27 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=167.94.138.138 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=43 ID=13258 PROTO=TCP SPT=53397 DPT=102 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  kernel
9:27 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=146.88.241.44 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=53 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=242 ID=54321 PROTO=UDP SPT=43322 DPT=27017 LEN=33 kernel
9:26 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=5.252.195.36 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xE0 TTL=56 ID=22080 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46672 DPT=22 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:26 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=45.128.232.212 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xE0 TTL=247 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=38716 DPT=8080 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:26 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=211.114.69.184 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=58836 PROTO=TCP SPT=16329 DPT=37215 WINDOW=4833 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=148.245.128.156 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=60 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=44 ID=56354 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=42167 DPT=23 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=107.170.254.26 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=41797 DPT=53 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=169.197.150.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=514 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=40048 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=55724 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=169.197.150.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=142 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=29710 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=55684 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=169.197.150.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=514 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=40047 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=55724 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=169.197.150.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=142 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=29709 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=55684 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=169.197.150.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=103 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=29708 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=55684 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:25 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=169.197.150.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=514 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=40042 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=55724 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 kernel
9:24 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=103.147.13.154 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=2502 PROTO=TCP SPT=56556 DPT=58263 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0    kernel
9:24 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=91.92.246.221 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=40648 DPT=22 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  kernel
9:24 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=103.248.123.164 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=33488 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62458 DPT=7680 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.26.9.145 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=20558 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=58691 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0    kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=50.116.18.173 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239 ID=44438 PROTO=TCP SPT=52052 DPT=8752 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=218.159.32.73 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=840 PROTO=TCP SPT=52967 DPT=37215 WINDOW=41607 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=8.18.47.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=142 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=41799 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=4551 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0  kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.55.232 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=79 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=7223 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=57935 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0    kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.55.232 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=79 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=7222 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=57935 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0    kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.55.232 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=7221 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=57935 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0    kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.55.232 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=7220 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=57935 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0    kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.51.98 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=79 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=33630 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=4305 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.51.98 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=79 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=33629 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=4305 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.51.98 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=33628 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=4305 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=104.22.51.98 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=33627 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=4305 WINDOW=8 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=8.18.47.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=142 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=41798 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=4551 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0  kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=199.45.155.16 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=51357 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55214 DPT=3306 WINDOW=42340 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  kernel
9:23 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=8.18.47.7 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=142 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=41797 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=4551 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0  kernel
9:22 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=79.124.56.186 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xE0 TTL=247 ID=63928 PROTO=TCP SPT=50255 DPT=7865 WINDOW=1025 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:22 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=79.124.56.186 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xE0 TTL=247 ID=62166 PROTO=TCP SPT=50239 DPT=2665 WINDOW=1025 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:22 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=79.124.56.186 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xE0 TTL=247 ID=62867 PROTO=TCP SPT=50239 DPT=9213 WINDOW=1025 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 kernel
9:21 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=15.235.196.36 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=105 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=29418 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=443 DPT=50852 LEN=85    kernel
9:21 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=172.233.142.191 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=40311 PROTO=TCP SPT=52062 DPT=9683 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
9:21 AM [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[MY_SERVER_MAC_ADDRESS] SRC=71.6.146.186 DST=[MY_SERVER_LOCAL_IP] LEN=44 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=118 ID=8270 PROTO=TCP SPT=29011 DPT=5900 WINDOW=6847 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0   kernel
```

On when googled for it then found the post mentioned about only recurring requests from same IP but these have different IP and port.

I am just getting started my Ubuntu server 22.04 since last couple of months, so not much idea what is actually happening here. Any help will be appreciated.

- Are these requests from random bots hitting my server?
- What should be my next steps?

Comment: 1. Yes, automated port scanning of the entire internet is common these days 2. Ignore it unless you care about the logspam. In that case, contact your cloud provider or ISP to see if they can put a Firewall in front of your server to block ports you don't need

Comment: Thank you, that clears my doubts.